# Jquery lightbox doesnt work with AdGallery

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, gallery, lightbox

Im using AdGallery for creating an image gallery (following this plugin : http://coffeescripter.com/2009/07/ad-gallery-a-jquery-gallery-plugin/).

And Jquery lightbox : http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Now I want this, when user click on the large image, a lightbox appears. So I modified some lines of code in jquery.ad-gallery.js:

from

```
if(image.link) {
          var link = $('<a rel="lightbox" href="'+ image.link +'" target="_blank"></a>');
          link.append(img);
          img_container.append(link);
        } else {
         img_container.append(img);
        }
```

to

```
if(image.link) {
          var link = $('<a rel="lightbox" href="'+ image.link +'" target="_blank"></a>');
          link.append(img);
          img_container.append(link);
        } else {
         var link = $('<a href="'+ image.image +'" rel="lightbox" class="lightbox"></a>');
         link.append(img);
          img_container.append(link);
        }
```

But when I click on the large image, nothing happened.

I did have these code in my html:

```
$(function() {
   $('#gallery a').lightBox();
});
```

What was I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of:

```
$(function() {
$('#gallery a').lightBox();
});
```

Use:

```
$(function() {
$('a.lightbox').each(function () { $(this).lightBox(); });
});
```

This prevents lightbox from showing a 'Next' option to other graphics in the div with strange results and prevents lightbox from getting attached to the thumbnails.

Because ad-gallery flushes the ad-image div contents when you change images, also add

```
$('a.lightbox').each(function () { $(this).lightBox(); });
```

at the end of the _showWhenLoaded: function in jquery.ad-gallery.js so that the lighbox event gets attached to each image when it's selected.

Answer (score 2):

I myself got this working with great difficulty.

The idea being that the main image in the slideshow popups to the large lightbox popup.

The issues to solve are:

lightbox looks for existing elements and makes an image array, but here we only have one dynamic item to work on at a time. 
The dynamic element we want lightbox to find is dynamic, so we need to use some dynamic jQuery method rather than the default method.
We want lightbox to know about all the images in the slideshow even though it will only find one main image.
We want lightbox to find the text associated with the images.

To solve:

Make sure you are putting the path to the big popups in the longdesc attribute of the thumbs, that way ad-gallery will put them in the href attribute around the slide image, and lightBox will find them

Use the callbacks in ad-gallery to call a lightbox load for every slide.

```
        $(function() {

            gallery1 = $('#gallery1').adGallery( 

                         { 
                            callbacks: 
                                {afterImageVisible: 
                                   function(){

                //lightBox loading stuff here

                dynamically find the title text and put it into the title of the link so lightBox can use it
                if( this.images[ this.current_index ].title )
                {
                        $(document).find( '.ad-image a' ).attr('title', this.images[ this.current_index ].title ); 
                }

                //use jQuery find to get the dynamic element then apply lightBox to it
               $(document).find( '#gallery1 .ad-image a' ).lightBox({ imageArray: aImagesFullSizeLightBox, fixedNavigation: true });

                //note, the "imageArray: aImagesFullSizeLightBox". This was my code addition to lightBox, which allowed me to tell lightBox what the imageArray is rather than trying to find them itself. You need to construct this array beforehand (see example below) in the correct format for lightBox to use, and you need to make code changes to lightBox to tell it to use it.



                                          } 
                             }  
                      });

    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//example array to pass to lightBox, make sure the above function can see it

var aImagesFullSizeLightBox = [];

aImagesFullSizeLightBox.push( new Array( '/images/bigPopupImage1.jpg','The Title Here 1') );

aImagesFullSizeLightBox.push( new Array( '/images/bigPopupImage2.jpg','The Title Here 2') );


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

//code changes needed to lightBox (this was done to version 0.5 which may be old now!)

$.fn.lightBox = function(settings) {

        //addition to support next and backs without lightbox taking control of   clicks on thumbs 3/6/2012 Gordon Rouse
        if( settings.imageArray )
            settings.setImagesExternally = true;
        else
            settings.setImagesExternally = false;

/////ALSO////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


function _start(objClicked,jQueryMatchedObj) {

            $('embed, object, select').css({ 'visibility' : 'hidden' });

            _set_interface();

            // Unset total images in imageArray
            //addition to support next and backs without lightbox taking control of clicks on thumbs - Gordon Rouse
            if ( !settings.setImagesExternally )
                settings.imageArray.length = 0;

            //settings.imageArray.length = 0;  //undo line for above!

            settings.activeImage = 0;

                        //here we stop lighBox trying to load the images it found
            if (!settings.setImagesExternally )
            {
                if ( jQueryMatchedObj.length == 1 ) {
                    settings.imageArray.push(new Array(objClicked.getAttribute('href'),objClicked.getAttribute('title')));
                } else {
                    // Add an Array (as many as we have), with href and title atributes, inside the Array that storage the images references        
                    for ( var i = 0; i < jQueryMatchedObj.length; i++ ) {
                        settings.imageArray.push(new Array(jQueryMatchedObj[i].getAttribute('href'),jQueryMatchedObj[i].getAttribute('title')));
                    }
                }
            }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

An example of this working is found here:

http://www.vikingkayaks.co.nz/shop/kayaks?product=1

but note there are other complex things in this example, so I have tried to distil the important parts in the description above.